# Submitting a form to one of two different URL's

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net, webforms, submit

I have two different buttons like this :

```
<input type="button" name="but1" id="but1" value="page1" onclick="f('WebForm1')" />
<input type="button" name="but2" id="but2" value="page2" onclick="f('WebForm2')" />
```

and obviously two other webforms ("WebForm1" and "WebForm2").

using JavaScript, how can I submit the information from the default webform (which I have the buttons in it) to the page that is the value of its button?

(I mean when I click the first button, it should go to WebForm1 and submit data and when I click the second button, it should go to WebForm2 and submit the data)

I've never tried this before so in JavaScript I wrote

```
function f(t){
var a;
a = document.getElementById['form1'];
a.submit(t);  }
```

but its not working.

Comment: can you post you code?

Comment: Is 'WebForm1' a valid URL on your system, since you post to it?

Comment: @KapilaPerera actually this the whole code. I'm trying this in order to use it in a project I've got

Comment: @Marcel yes it is. I've tried posting to only one webform using only one button and one function and it worked. I just have problem with multiple webforms and buttons using one function

Answer (score 1):

Are all these functionalities to be implemented on the same page?
How I see it, you can make the two input buttons the submit buttons of the two different forms.

```
<form action = "WebForm1">
    <input type= submit  name="but1" id="but1" value="page1" />
</form>

<form action = "WebForm2">
    <input type= submit name="but2" id="but2" value="page2" />
</form>
```

Also, I'm not sure if anything like *a.submit(t)* even works.

Comment: a.submit() works. but I'm not sure if we can have 2 forms in a server side website

Comment: Maybe you can use the `onclick()` function on the buttons and give the absolute paths to your forms.

Answer (score 0):

In **HTML5** you can use `<button>` with form attribute:

```
<button type="submit" form="form1" value="Submit">Submit</button>
```

with `form` attribute you can specify the form element the `<button>` element belongs to.

Then, in your form:

```
<form action="WebForm1" method="get" id="form1">
...
</form>
```

Comment: The method should probably be POST. Also, the OP wants to post to one of two targets, how to have that with just one submit button to that form?

Answer (score 0):

hope this will help. t is the name of the form.

```
function f(t){
    // <form name="WebForm1">
    // t is the name of the form
    document.t.submit();
}
```

this work only if the two form are in the same page as where the button are.